# how to make php json decode pagination

Tags: php, json

I am looking for a php json pagination method/class. Here is my code. How to make each 2 json data as a group, for a pagination?

```
$body = file_get_contents("out_file.txt");
$json = json_decode($body,true);
foreach($json as $data){
    echo $data['name'].' '; 
}
```

out_file.txt

```
[
    {"name":"text1","num":"1"},
    {"name":"text2","num":"2"},
    {"name":"text3","num":"3"},
    {"name":"text4","num":"4"},
    {"name":"text5","num":"5"},
    {"name":"text6","num":"6"}
]
```

I need divide data like this:

*page1*

text1
text2

*page2*

text3
text4

*page3*

text5
text6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON data is not a "display" medium... it's a data transfer format. How you do pageination of the data within the JSON body is up to you, but that's true of ANY data structure, not just JSON. Given that your sample JSON structure is an array, you'd simply do some array indexing with your "page" offsets:

```
$page = 2;
$items_per_page = 2;

echo $json[$page * $items_per_page]['name'] // $json[4] -> text5
echo $json[$page * $items_per_page + 1]['name'] // $json[5] -> text6
```

Answer (score 5):

`json_decode($body,true)` **returns an array of associative arrays** in place of the JSON objects specified in your file. Knowing that you have an array containing all the elements you want to cycle through you can use a generic pagination function to control which data is displayed. Something like...

```
$body = file_get_contents("out_file.txt");
$json = json_decode($body,true);
paginate($json,$pageNumber);

function paginate($data, $page = 1, $perPage = 2) {
   $x = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
   $z = $page * $perPage;
   $y = ($z > count($data)) ? count($data) : $z;
   for(; $x < $y; $x++) {
      echo $data[$x]['name'];
   }
}
```